# Hiding dynamically generated divs on 'Click Event'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a project where I have created 4 divs dynamically, with first as "display:block". When I click next, I will get second div as "display:block" and 1st, 3rd, 4th as "display:none"; The problem is when I click the next button fast 2 times - 2 divs get "display:block" and both are seen on the screen. I have tried the following code, but I am fed up of this. Is there any way to control the show-hide of dynamically generated divs?

```
 <script>

/* First check up that only one div must show on click of my 4 clickable buttons - failed .. ;( */ 

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('span#backPage').click(function(){
                var alpha1 = $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','block');
                $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','none');
                alpha1.css('display','block');
            });
            $('span#nextPage').click(function(){
                var alpha1 = $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','block');
                $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','none');
                alpha1.css('display','block');
            });
            $('span#prevField').click(function(){
                var alpha1 = $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','block');
                $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','none');
                alpha1.css('display','block');
            });
           $('span#nextField').click(function(){
                var alpha1 = $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','block');
                $('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','none');
                alpha1.css('display','block');
            });

/* This is double check that only 1 div must show at one time - but failing too */

           if($('div#step_0').css('display','block')){$('div.step').css('display','none');$(this).css('display','block');}

           if($('div#step_1').css('display','block')){$('div.step').css('display','none');$(this).css('display','block');}

           if($('div#step_2').css('display','block')){$('div.step').css('display','none');$(this).css('display','block');}

           if($('div#step_3').css('display','block')){$('div.step').css('display','none');$(this).css('display','block');}

        });

     </script>
```

If someone can help me out of this mess-of multiple display:block of dynamically genearted divs, I would be glad! ;( I have tried hide() for all and show() for selected one.
I have tried everything but still the problem persists. I dont know how to get all other divs hide if new one gets blocked!

Comment: add your html please

Comment: Looks like you are doing `$('div.ui-formwizard-content').css('display','block').css('display','block');` with the var alpha1. I usually like using `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of `.css('display', 'none');` as well

Comment: Looks like you are setting the display to block then to none then back to block for the element too. Maybe just `$('div.ui-formwizard-content').show();`?

Comment: I have tried hide() for all and show() for selected one.

Comment: Please add the html as @Ted said. The code is confusing and unnecessarily bloated. With the html we can help you streamline this and get it working.

Comment: Nothing much just its a wizard in which 4 divs are dynamically generating. On slow 'next' button all come one by one. But, if I try too fast. 2 divs come together instead of One. The whole problem is because of these dynamic generation instead of static. But, that's the way my boss wants. I need a conditions so that as soon as next click happens, Only one div is seen, and other 3 are hidden, whatsoever might happen!

Comment: Point being, your code shows a lot of unnecessary repetition, which, with the HTML, we can figure out better what is going wrong and help you simplify and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and untested. Mainly to show your unnecessary code. Perhaps it will help you track down your problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('span#backPage').click(function(){
            showAlpha(this);
        });
        $('span#nextPage').click(function(){
            showAlpha(this);
        });
        $('span#prevField').click(function(){
            showAlpha(this);
        });
       $('span#nextField').click(function(){
            showAlpha(this);
        });

        function showAlpha(_this) {
            var alpha1 = $('div.ui-formwizard-content');
            alpha1.show();
            // Get the correct active child here html would help figure out how in your case
            var child = ???;
            $('div.step').hide();
            $(child).show();
        }

    });
```

Edited